# What happened to the Resources tab in Chrome canary?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using the latest version of the Chrome browser, Chrome canary 54.0.2807.1 (64-bit) and trying to find the Resources tab, so I can look at cookies, but there is no Resources tab!

Here's what I'm doing:

1) Launch Chrome canary.
2) Navigate to a website, say google.com.
3) Press F12 to open the developer tools.
4) Notice the Resources tab is missing...

I'm sure the info is there somewhere, but if you can help me with this, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Found it.  The tab formerly known as Resources is now named Application, and the contents has been reorganized a bit.  Here are some screen shots:

The Chrome Resources tab:

[image]

The Chrome canary Application tab:

[image]